# How od I make sure Codebuild stage never fails even if there is error?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am trying to run 3 stages in Codebuild in parallel and I want to run Codebuild even if it fails for demonstration purposes. How do I make sure that Codebuild never fails even if exit status from command is not 0?

I tried on-failure as well as exit 0 but nothing worked.

Here's my buildspec.yaml file:

```
{
  "version": "0.2",
  "phases": {
    "pre_build": {
      "commands": [
        "echo Installing SCA tool...",
        "pip install pip-audit"
      ]
    },
    "build": {
      "on-failure": "CONTINUE",
      "commands": [
        "echo Jatin",
        "echo Entered the post_build phase...",
        "echo Build completed on `date`",
        "pip-audit -r requirements.txt"
      ],
      "finally": [
        "exit 0"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to make your build actual work for demonstration purposes?

Answer (score 0):

You're example is in JSON not YAML which I'm not sure is supported: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-syntax

Providing the build details would be helpful
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/view-build-details.html